# How to add CLSID and IID in header file with MIDL?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, com, midl

Here is a test IDL file:

```
import "unknwn.idl";

[uuid(f531223f-43bb-49d4-80fc-30ceb5f4f990)]
coclass test
{
    interface Itest;
}

[uuid(deb8730f-f811-4cb3-bd8f-b1601926bd48)]
interface Itest : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT function(int var);
};
```

When I run `midl test.idl` command it does not add the CLSID in `test.h` header file. But WIDL from mingw-w64 (derived from wine project) adds CLSID and IID both in header file.

After using library attribute as this:

```
import "unknwn.idl";

[uuid(82c87f04-887a-41b2-9c2d-0f3a6a973efd)]
library testLib
{
    [uuid(f531223f-43bb-49d4-80fc-30ceb5f4f990)]
    coclass test
    {
        interface Itest;
    }
};

[uuid(deb8730f-f811-4cb3-bd8f-b1601926bd48)]
interface Itest : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT function(int var);
};
```

Those GUIDs are embraced in C++ and EXTERN_C. And mentioned in separate C file but not in the header file.

How can I do the same with MIDL? Or am I doing anything wrong in IDL file?

Comment: MIDL requires you to put the coclass inside a library {} block.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/library

Comment: Extern declaration in the header, definition in a source file, that's how the language works.  MIDL encourages using C++, writing COM code in C is outlawed by the Geneva convention on programmers rights.  The DECLSPEC_UUID macro powers MSVC++'s `__uuidof` operator so you don't need the guids at all.